# Ajax! One small fix needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am facing a very interesting problem.
i have the following code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=ZThhqk5mHkg",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'get',
      error: function(data) 
          {
            //
          }
    });
</script>
```

the problem is that, i want to get the source of that url. While i use OPERA INSPECTOR>Scripts tab, there is shown the target youtube source, but the script shows an error, and alerts other things.. i want to get the text, which is in OPERA debuger(If OPERA sees, that means, that the url source is got!).. how to output that javascript?

Comment: That isn't JSONP.  You can't do that, for security reasons.

Comment: and how opera gets that content, if user is not allowed to get the content?

Comment: opera is the browser, it can do whatever it likes to. It is opera that implements the security policy that disallows *pages* from ajaxing to out of domain servers.

Comment: you might be able to use youtubes api as it supports CORS headers ... http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/05/unlocking-javascripts-potential-with.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three parties involved:

- The author of the site running the JavaScript
- The author of the site which is in the `url` parameter
- The user of the browser visiting the first site

The purpose of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is to prevent the first site from using the browser user's identity to get data from the second site.

This means that the JavaScript from the first site is now allowed access to the HTTP response.

The Opera Debugger is under the control of the user of the browser, not the author of the first site, so it *is* allowed access to that data.

In order to access the information on a third party site, you must use one of the [techniques to circumvent the Same Origin Policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). They all require either the cooperation of the second site or to have something other than the user's browser interact with the site.

JSONP, which you are trying to use, is one such option (it falls into the cooperation category), but it requires that the response be expressed as JSONP (which it isn't).

Google provide [a JavaScript API for YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript). If you want to interact with YouTube, then you should use that.